# Why "Error loading column family" in OpsCenter when reading Column Family?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

I'm trying to use the OpsCenter with my local multi-node development cluster created with CCM. I have manually installed and configured the Agents for each node using [these instructions](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/running-opscenter-with-a-local-development-cluster).  I created my custom keyspace and its column families by uploading a SOURCE file in the CQLSH interface

I get the following error when clicking on Data > MyKeySpace > MyColumnFamily:

```
Error loading column family: Call to /test_cluster/keyspaces/flashcardsapp/cf/tag timed out.
```

I am however able to view the column families in the OpsCenter keyspace.

I am seeing the following in the OpsCenter log:

```
2015-03-14 07:58:35-0600 [] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/justinrobbins/Documents/dev/cassandra/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-osx/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1076, in gotResult
        _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
      File "/Users/justinrobbins/Documents/dev/cassandra/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-osx/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1063, in _inlineCallbacks
        deferred.callback(e.value)
      File "/Users/justinrobbins/Documents/dev/cassandra/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-osx/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 361, in callback
        self._startRunCallbacks(result)
      File "/Users/justinrobbins/Documents/dev/cassandra/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-osx/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 455, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/Users/justinrobbins/Documents/dev/cassandra/opscenter-5.1.0/lib/py-osx/2.7/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 542, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/TwistedRouter.py", line 226, in controllerSucceeded

      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 3953, in default_write

      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
        sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
        chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
        return _iterencode(o, 0)
      File "build/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opscenterd/WebServer.py", line 261, in default

      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
        raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
    exceptions.TypeError: UUID('457d5450-ca0b-11e4-a99a-53fff8597215') is not JSON serializable
```

My environment is as follows:

- Cassandra: `dsc-cassandra-2.1.2`
- OpsCenter: `opscenter-5.1.0`
- Agents: `datastax-agent-5.1.0`
- OS: `OSX 10.10.1`

Answer (score 3):

There’s a known bug in OpsCenter where UUID columns in Cassandra 2.1.x are not handled properly. I am not aware of any workarounds (switching from UUID columns or downgrading C* to 2.0.x should work, but it might be a bit too much work.)

It’s going to be fixed in the upcoming patch release of OpsCenter 5.1 (not 5.1.1 though)